# There are alternative ways to unlock the screen other than writing the password?

Tags: screen, unlock

Can I unlock the stand-by screen with a pattern (like in Android phones), or face recognition?

Comment: Has anyone been able to get gestures, or some sort of pin (for touch screen only devices) running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anthentication in Ubuntu is handled using [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module). Looking for PAM modules, you'll find alternative ways to authenticate, and playing with PAM configuration, you'll be able to enable / disable thoses modules depending on the context.

For example, you can have a look at [pam-face-authentication](http://code.google.com/p/pam-face-authentication/).

Another alternative is using Fingerprint readers with libpam-fprintd (see [here](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fprint))

Each pam module provides integration guide, but beware, it's quite easy to lock you out of your system when playing with PAM configuration!

Comment: does this method works for all the pc's?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - need a compatible fingerprint reader and/or webcam  to start... :-(

Comment: so i will try with ubuntu virtual machines first!