# Pattern Lock Screens

Tags: lock-screen

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 2 and after getting some things tweaked so it's usable **converted** (i.e. *tablet-mode*).
I have one remaining issue - I need the keyboard to unlock.

I'm curious if there are any good lock-screen utils or modifications which would allow me to use a **pattern or PIN lock** system on login and when the lock kicks on.

Comment: This forum should help.
[FORUM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401584/there-are-alternative-ways-to-unlock-the-screen-other-than-writing-the-password) G,Luck